# Select parts of Input Cell

Tags: cells

One of my cells contains some Text and Input:

```
some text 3+5,
```

so the expression underlying this looks like

```
Cell[  TextData[{ 
    "some text ",
     StyleBox["3+5", "Output"]
        }],   "Text"]
```

I now wish to select only the "3+5", using commands, as to be able to evaluate that part *in place*, as if one uses the command "Evaluate in Place" of the Evaluation menu (and using the notebook end to manually select 3+5).

I've tried using Cases[ ... , StyleBox[__]], but this gives an empty set. What am I missing here?

Once again, thanks for all help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to replace all output-style boxes with evaluated values. You can do this by

```
Module[{nb = EvaluationNotebook[], sel = Null},
 SelectionMove[nb, Before, Notebook, AutoScroll -> False];
  While[sel =!= {},
   SelectionMove[nb, Next, Cell, AutoScroll -> False];
   sel = NotebookRead[nb];
   If[MatchQ[sel, Cell[_, "Text", ___]], 
    NotebookWrite[nb, sel /. StyleBox[expr_, "Output"] :> 
     StyleBox[ToString[ToExpression[expr], InputForm], "Output"]
]]]]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is indeed what I was looking for, but I wonder: why aren't you using SelectionEvaluate[]? Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Second question: Why the need for ToString? Furthermore, this doesn't seem to work when using exponents in symbolic forms... Any help with that?

Comment: @Gabriel I don't use `SelectionEvaluate` because I select whole cell and I want to evaluate only output-style boxes in it. Without `ToString` examples like `a+b` don't works. I edit my post to correct the problem with exponents.